# How does Solr know which row to return when I set the limit to 1?

Tags: java, solr

In solrQuery when I set the rows to one, how does solr know which one to return ? The first one? By default sort?

PD: What does mean the default sort (score desc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Solr will sort result by default using score value (`score desc`) and will return first one document. You can read more about it [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort)